# how to check not exist header field with supertest?

Tags: node.js, express, supertest

If I set the express.js like this:

```
app.set("x-powered-by", false);
```

How to test this?

```
.expect('X-Powered-By', '', done)
```

will throw error: `Error: expected "X-Powered-By" header field`

```
.expect('X-Powered-By', null, done)
```

also not works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest creating custom validation as follows:

```
it('should validate header is not present.', function(done){
  request
    .get('/path/to/your/resource')
    .end(function(error, response){
      if (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
      // Here is where we identify is header exists or not
      var isHeaderPresent = response.header['header-to-validate'] !== undefined;
      isHeaderPresent.should.be.False();
      done();
    });
});
```

Note also that this example uses `should` library for its validations.

Comment: thanks, leo, btw, do you know why this kind of api is not part of supertest? just because few people need it? or I use the wrong paradigms?

Comment: Probably because it is not a common use case. At least, I did not face that case before.

Answer (score 8):

This is the assert you need (using Jest):

`.expect((res) => expect(res.headers['X-Powered-By']).toBeUndefined())`